# SSIS connection issue Sqlstate: hy000 sqlcode: -1004

Tags: sql, ssis, db2

While connecting to DB2 through SSIS, we are facing below issue :
`DB2OLEDB_AUTHENTICATION_NOT_SUPPORTED -SQLSTATE: HY000 SQLCODE: -1004`.

Because of above issue we are unable to create connection. Please help

Comment: which task you using?

Comment: I am trying to create Connection through connection manager in ssis to extract from DB2 to SQL.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).